# iOS Facebook Share with mention

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to share to Facebook or create stories using Open Graph Stories. I have followed their example and I can share photo, action like this.

However, I need to mention page in my post. I am reading this 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#mentions

It describe how to do for mention. But I don't know how to call that one in iOS. May I know how to do?

```
// Construct an FBSDKSharePhoto
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"instruction1.jpg"];


// Optionally set user generated to YES only if this image was created by the user
// You must get approval for this capability in your app's Open Graph configuration
// photo.userGenerated = YES;

// Create an object
NSDictionary *properties = @{
                             @"og:type": @"books.book",
                             @"og:title": @"A Game of Thrones",
                             @"og:description": @"In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.",
                             @"books:isbn": @"0-553-57340-3",
                             };
FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

// Create an action
FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
action.actionType = @"books.reads";
[action setObject:object forKey:@"books:book"];


// Add the photo to the action. Actions
// can take an array of images.
[action setArray:@[photo] forKey:@"image"];


// Create the content
FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
content.action = action;
content.previewPropertyName = @"books:book";


[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:[AppDelegate instance].window.rootViewController
                             withContent:content
                                delegate:nil];
```

Edit: I have changed like this. First, I let user login to Facebook using Facebook login button. After that, I trigger this. I can successfully post to Facebook but I can't mention myself or I can't mention page. It just show either page ID or user ID. How shall I do?

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
{
    NSLog(@"User ID is %@", [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].userID);

    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a test message with page ID =  @[455272221218150]  and user ID = @[%@]",[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].userID];

    NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"message": msg, @"access_token": [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken], @"book": @"http://www.example.com/book/09485736/"
                             };
    /* make the API call */
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                  parameters:params
                                  HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
        // Handle the result
    }];


}
```

Comment: All you need is to put `@[id]` somewhere into the message value. But please be aware, that the message has to be a 100% user generated (and that includes tags) – your app is _not allowed_ to insert any tags automatically.

Comment: May i know where I need to put message value? Is it like                              @"og:message": @".......................",

Comment: You can not specify the message when using the Share dialog. You would need to make the post via API instead. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/ios#custom

Comment: Thanks. I can now post to Facebook but I can't mention myself or page. It just show page ID @[24242.....]. How shall I do?

Comment: Now you’re just making a normal post; you can not tag users in normal posts made via API. You still have to publish an Open Graph Story if you want to be able to tag.

Comment: Oh..I am finding but I can't. Is it to do with FBRequestConnection? Do I need to import anything? How can I publish open graph story?